# Missing data cells are partly empty instead of saying "NA"

Tags: r, csv, missing-data

I imported a .csv dataset into RStudio and now have the problem that not all cells that contain missing data are encoded with "NA" but are just empty. How do I transform those empty cells into cells with "NA"? Since the dataset is quite big, I cannot do it by selecting every single empty cell by hand. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have some code you can post? A Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Check what is in those empty cells. Most likely they have an empty string: `""`. In that case, just select those cells with bracket notation and insert `NA`:

`df[df == ""] <- NA`